# Ajax Serialize Need to get value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have the following ajax serialize:

```
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: $form.attr('action'),
         data: $form.serialize(),
         error: function (xhr, status, error) {
             ConfirmDialog('The page save failed.');
           },
      success: function (response) {
     // need to retrieve an output value from the controller here 

     }
});
```

When it does a post, I am doing to an ActionResult method. How do I pass a value from the ActionResult so that I can get the value of it in when it is successful (under where it says success:function(response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is in the response

```
 success: function(response) {
    alert( response ); 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I get pass a value from the controller though. Also would it be like response.IDVal = .. something in in the response.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry i don't know how to json encode values in asp.net. In php we just `echo json_encode( array('id' =>'value') )` then in the javascript you can access it via `response.id`